# linear regression using dataset with missing values

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, glmulti

I have data on the effect sizes for 14 variables (var1-var14). Each value is the effect size of a specific treatment on a certain variable. Missing values are due to that some articles did not consider certain variables. A positive value show promoting while a negative value shows the inhibiting effect of that treatment on the variable. I want (1) to do a pairwise linear regression that runs through each and every variable and compare if there is an association between variables, (2) consider var1 as the dependent variable and var2-var14 all as independent variables to find the best-fit model (maybe using `glmulti` package?) and show changes in which variables are most important for change in `var1`.

Here is a sample data:

```
set.seed(123)

**# Create the dataset with effect sizes and missing values**

mydata <- data.frame(
  Var1 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var2 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var3 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var4 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var5 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var6 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var7 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var8 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var9 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var10 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var11 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var12 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var13 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE),
  Var14 = sample(c(-20:14, NA), 64, replace = TRUE)
)

**# Set more than 50% missing values in each column**
for (col in 1:14) {
  missing_indices <- sample(1:64, size = 32)
  mydata[missing_indices, col] <- NA
}
```

Is it possible to do all this with such dataset (i.e., missing values)? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there is no *easy* "do statistical analysis with missing data" machinery. The standard approach is to use *multiple imputation* (e.g. see the `mice` package, but this is simply adding an additional layer on top of whatever you were doing already ...

Answer (score 1):

`d` being your example data:

```
d <- 
  paste0('Var_', 1:14) |>
  Map(f = \(.) sample(c(-20:14, NA),
                      size = 64,
                      prob = c(rep(.49/35, 35), .51),
                      replace = TRUE
                      )
      ) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

... you get the pairwise associations in terms of the correlation matrix like so:

```
d |> cor(use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
```

... and a basic column-wise imputation (replacing `NA` with the mean value) this way:

```
d_imputed <- d |>
  apply(2, \(var) replace(var, is.na(var), mean(var, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Finally you can obtain the regression coefficients of the predictors (columns) for each column like so:

```
d_imputed |> 
  apply(2, FUN = \(var) coef(lm(var ~ ., as.data.frame(d_imputed))))
```

A word of caution: above is just a technical answer to your literal question. For a statistically sound solution, I'd recommend researching over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) about imputation, dimensionality reduction, predictor selection and such (see Ben Bolker's comment).

Comment: Thanks but in the second last step, replacing NA with the mean value makes the overall analysis weak. I would be happy if we can do linear regression without replacing NA.

Comment: Well, for a 50% fraction of `NA` in every variable (as you specified), the chance for a complete observation of 14 variables (i. e. not having to deal with `NA`) is 1 in 16384 (0.5^14). Then you got *one* complete observation, let alone a proper sample size for linear regression.